# How to implement priority Queue in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, priority-queue

Is Priority Queue collection available in dart because I am not able to use priority queue in flutter?

If so, then please write a snippet of how to use it. I am not able to find any handy explanation of how to use Priority Queue in flutter.

Comment: `final queue = PriorityQueue<String>(); queue.add('foo'); queue.add('bar'); print(queue.toList());`

Comment: Thanks mate. Just one Qs how can we write custom comparator function for the above Priority Queue?

Comment: just pass it to `PriorityQueue` constructor - `PriorityQueue((e0, e1) => your_compare_logic_here)`

Comment: You need to explicitly import [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) to get the `PriorityQueue` implementation.  See [its documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/PriorityQueue-class.html) for more details.  [Its constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/PriorityQueue/PriorityQueue.html) takes a comparison callback.

Comment: We need to use package:collection in dart, but other languages provide inbuilt priorityQueue. However, when I used dart:collection, it is showing that PriorityQueue is deprecated. Why was priorityQueue of dart deprecated?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/PriorityQueue-class.html does not say it is deprecated

Comment: The non-Flutter version is not deprecated either: https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/PriorityQueue-class.html

Comment: What was deprecated was the imports of the internal package files: https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/dart.pkg.collection.priority_queue/dart.pkg.collection.priority_queue-library.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  // queue that prioritizes longer strings
  final queue = PriorityQueue<String>((a, b) => b.length.compareTo(a.length));
  queue..add('foo')..add('bazars')..add('zort');
  
  while (queue.isNotEmpty) {
    print('* ${queue.removeFirst()}');
  }
}
```

Docs at https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/PriorityQueue-class.html